# Does FirebaseOptions should be kept secret or can be available in source code without problems?

Tags: angular, firebase, security

I am currently developing an application with Angular using Firebase for basic authentication ( password + email ) and an API to access data. However I was wondering about the authentication part and in particular the FirebaseOptions object that is provided to initialize Firebase on Angular.
Do these values have to be strictly secret? If yes, how can I protect them so that they can't be found by looking at the source code because currently I put them in my envrionnement.ts but when we are on the site, it is possible to find the values by looking at the generated .js file...

The different solutions :

1. I stay like that because these values are not secret and can be accessible in the source code without worries
2. I remove them from the source code of my site and I manage the authentication system in my API by using the values of FirebaseOptions to check the credentials with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not need to be kept secret.

From the docs:

> API keys for Firebase are different from typical API keys
>
> Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services are not used to control access to backend resources; that can only be done with Firebase Security Rules (to control which users can access resources) and App Check (to control which apps can access resources).
>
> Usually, you need to fastidiously guard API keys (for example, by using a vault service or setting the keys as environment variables); however, API keys for Firebase services are ok to include in code or checked-in config files.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys

For future reference, it's impossible to hide keys in a front end browser application. If you were letting users use a secret API key you would create a back end server and add the key as an environment variable on the machine, not in the code.